# Supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code which generates the following message. I have used `mysql_num_rows()` before without any issue and even though it is now giving me a warning it still shows the results.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
$days_ago1 = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") , date("d") - 1, date("Y")));
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM daily_count WHERE date='$days_ago1' and  member ='$site_id'");
$num_rows1 = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

and this is the warning:

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/track003/public_html/livetrack/data/graph_data.php on line 5
```

Line 5 is the last line of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Does the query run when you paste it into a mysql client command line?

```
echo "SELECT * FROM daily_count WHERE date='$days_ago1' and  member ='$site_id'";
```

and put it in mysql and see does it return rows.

Comment: In short no, but it displays the results now, it just also provides an error

Comment: Thanks but it already returns the results, so i can't see what putting it through mysql will show?

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query` returns `FALSE` when the query fails for whatever reason. You should always check the return value:

```
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die('DB ERROR: '.mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: ok, but it is showing a result?

Comment: any chance you are fetching the results from a different query? `mysql_num_rows` doesn't lie, if it says the resource is not valid it's not.

Comment: OK I SOLVED IT, I DON'T KNOW HOW BUT I COPIED AND PASTE THE INFO FROM ANOTHER PAGE ADJUSTED THAT AND IT WORKED.....  THANKS FOR YOUR HELP